# How to count total and null values in AngularJs object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to count total `not null` fields out of `total` fields in my angularjs object, then I want to calculate the percentage.

eg:

in my object contain 10 fields.two fields have some values(others `null`).

`Completed = (not null fields/total fields)*100`
           `= (4/11)*100 = 36.36%`

**my controller**

```
myApp.controller('PController', function ($scope,localStorageService) {

$scope.user = localStorageService.get("user");

console.log(Object.keys($scope.user).length);
});
```

now i can get total fields.but how can i count `not null` fields and callculate percentage?

**$scope.user object is like below**

```
{
    "user_id": "205",
    "first_name": null,
    "last_name": null,
    "email": "at@yuib.com",
    "address": null,
    "mobile": null,
    "phone": null,
    "profile_img": null,
    "gender": null,
    "registered": "1",
    "addresses": 0
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simple filter method with Object.keys on the $scope.user should give the required result

```
Object.keys($scope.user).filter(x=>$scope.user[x]!==null).length
```

Comment: It's showing `'arrow function syntax (=>)' is only available in ES6 angularjs`

Comment: yes you need to use babel https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/ to transpile ES6 to ES5 or else replace => by regular function

Comment: so it will become Object.keys($scope.user).filter(function(x){ return $scope.user[x]!==null})

Comment: or if its ESLint warning use eslint config to enable eslint for ES6 in your editor http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Comment: yes this is helped.but you have to add `length` at the end.any way this is great help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Object.values($scope.user).filter((item) => item != null).length
```